# How can i insert a character in every specific character like "(" inside my string - javascript

Tags: javascript, string

for example:

```
x = "This is my string(string) another string(string)";
```

what i want to do is to insert a single quote after `(` and before `)` each.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
var startStr = "This is my string(string) another string(string)";
var endStr = startStr.replace(/\(/g, '(\'').replace(/\)/g, '\'\)');
console.log(endStr); //This is my string('string') another string('string')
```

Answer (score 1):

Jack's answer is very short, which is good.
If you're the kind of person who likes a process that easier to understand, but longer, here goes...

```
    var myString = "This is my string(string) another string(string)";

    myString = myString.split("(");
    myString = myString.join("('");
    myString = myString.split(")");
    myString = myString.join("')");

    console.log(myString);
```

Comment: Sure, using `split` in this way is a nice technique, but it's four times slower than using replace.

Comment: True, but sometimes people don't mind trading milliseconds for legibility. Just another option really.